# "Message=unknown error: cannot focus element" while executing tests through Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send key for a drop down list in google chrome browser but i am receiving this error

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
   at BnI.UITests.Register.TheOfficialInfoValidTest() in C:\Users\me\UITests\Register.cs:line 382
```

This is my method :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Country:'])[1]/following::span[2]")).SendKeys("USA");
```

This how its look in html :

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-xs-8 no-padding-sides ng-star-inserted" style="">
   <kendo-dropdownlist _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-dropdown k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="countryId" dir="ltr">
      <span role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" id="k-d0697a91-baeb-4960-bfc1-c023903c1159" dir="ltr" readonly="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dbfc0894-a4f5-4f1b-881f-1d88ccdc6002" aria-activedescendant="f65cbfa2-6280-4a84-908b-ba11da75d59d-undefined">
         <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">
            <!----><!---->Select Country ...
         </span>
         <span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span class="k-i-arrow-s k-icon"></span></span><!---->
      </span>
      <!----><!---->
   </kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>
```

This is the XPath :

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Country:'])[1]/following::span[2]
```

This how dropdownlist value look like if i want to click on it using selenium IDE because this value is retrieved from database :

1. First i clicked on the dropdownlist
2. Second i selected the country

[image]

Is there another way to add value by keyboard in selenium instead of send key ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Done . Check now

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: now is better ?

Comment: Great job @JamesFallon Can you publish a bit more of the surrounding html? It's tough to analyze and test such a smaller html as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have shared the target element is a `<span>` tag so you won't be able to invoke `SendKeys()` method. Instead you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired element to be clickable and you can use either of the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[@class='k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default' and @role='listbox']/span[@class='k-input']"))).Click();
//or
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[@class='k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default' and @role='listbox']//span[@class='k-select']"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(WebdriverName);
actions.moveToElement(locator).click();
```

You can use Actions library to solve issue. moveToElement enables the element to be focused by webdriver. Also when you create driver name make a wait method with ExpectedCondition.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebdriverName, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName(locator)));
```