# unknown error: cannot focus element using ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through VB Net

Tags: vb.net, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I face the error cannot focus element. it looks like

[image]

i have no idea for fix it, this is what I was did, can anyone help me to fix it?

```
Try
        Dim options As ChromeOptions = FrmWABot.options
        options = New ChromeOptions
        options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=" & Application.StartupPath & "/profile")
        Clipboard.SetText(no)
        Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@title='Search or start new chat']"))
        Clipboard.SetText(no)
        With element
            .SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v")
            .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
        End With
        Dim elpesan As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"))

        With elpesan
            Clipboard.SetImage(getImage())
            .SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v")
            .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
        End With

        Dim element1 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]"))
        element1.Click()
        With element1
            Clipboard.SetText("Happy Birthday...")
            .SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v")
            .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.ToString()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
unknown error: cannot focus element (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to focus on the **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Presumably you are using *chrome= 77.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v77.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 77**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.38* and the *Chrome Browser v77.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.

> You can find a relevant discussion in [“Message=unknown error: cannot focus element” while executing tests through Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036559/message-unknown-error-cannot-focus-element-while-executing-tests-through-sele/52039048#52039048)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use action class instead of regular script

```
Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
```